# Image doesn't display in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox

In my aspx file ,

```
<div id="blueBar">
        <div style="position: absolute;">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/blueBar_01.jpg" Width="150px"
                Style="margin-top: 4px" /><br />
        </div>
        <div style="top: 35%; position: absolute">
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/blueBar_02.jpg" Width="150px" /><br />
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0">
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/blueBar_03.jpg" Width="150px" /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Firefox browser can display the images (Image1,Image2,Image3).
But Internet Explorer can't display ! I see the cross signs .   I want to know why and how to solve ?
I use IE version (8.0.7601.17514)

Comment: Be sure to check the source code and see what exactly is being generated for your images source.  You should be able to figure where it is pointing and correct it from there.

Answer (score 1):

if your Style folder is at root level,Try like :-

```
<div id="blueBar">
        <div style="position: absolute;">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Styles/images/blueBar_01.jpg" Width="150px"
                Style="margin-top: 4px" /><br />
        </div>
        <div style="top: 35%; position: absolute">
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="Styles/images/blueBar_02.jpg" Width="150px" /><br />
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0">
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="Styles/images/blueBar_03.jpg" Width="150px" /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
```